# ng-pageslide scrolling to page height

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, css

I have used ng-pageslide as the modal poping from right and have used overlay by setting ps-body-class to true, but my problem is as I scroll my modal even the contents behind the overlay scrolls.
So does anyone have a solution for this?

Please let me know if anyone had the same issue or anyone knows the solution

Thank you.